# Use a table in another database in Sequel::Model

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I am using Sequel with MySQL database and Padrino. To get stats from my database I'm using:

```
class Stats < Sequel::Model(:"#{OTHER_DB}__stats")
end
```

OTHER_DB is the name of the database where the stats table is located. Everything works fine and I'm successfully getting the stats when using this class, but when starting padrino I'm getting this error:

```
FATAL - [30/Apr/2012 11:33:29] "Mysql2::Error: Table 'api_test.stats' doesn't exist: DESCRIBE stats"
```

api_test is the name of the default database that is being used when I don't specify anything else.

Why am I getting this error? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Does this relate to what you're experiencing? http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.sequel/4292 If so, it seems to be related to Sequel and can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Sequel.  It'll be fixed in the tomorrow's release of 3.35.0.